# SQL Time Has Passed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite

I thought of making a time has passed since last time it has been inserted in SQLITE so my solution looks like this:

```
if($n==1) { $db->exec("INSERT INTO progress (user,time,count) VALUES ('$user',0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"); }
//after 10 minutes $n becomes 2
if($n==2) { $db->exec("UPDATE progress SET time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - count"); }
```

The issue is that time remains to be 0 for some reason. Any ideas what I have wrong?

**More details:**

```
(table)process[id,user,time,count]
//what I display from this table is user and time
count = Time at creation of the row,
time = 0 at creation of the row,
//Updating the row after some time has passed
time = current_time - count
```

Comment: Why don't you create two columns, created, modified. And update modified column on update, and get the time difference between modified and created as progress?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**IMPORTANT WARNING:**

Your code is open to SQL injection! using prepared statements and binding your parameters is highly recommended to prevent malicious code being used on your database.

**ANSWER for educational purposes:**

- you have a typo at:  `('$user,0,`. You should have two apostrophes, one before and one after: `('$user',0,`
- Also, after asking about the `count` word in your second query, you mentioned it was a column:

  ```
     "UPDATE progress SET time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - count"
  ```

Trying to subtract `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - count` is like trying to subtract a number by an array: `4 - array("hi", 5);`. It doesn't make sense and your database is probably misinterpreting what you are trying to do, hence causing your error.

*But please use prepared statements and bind your parameters. Not only will then your code work, but it will be safe :)*

---

**On request by the OP**, here is an example of a prepared statement:

Your first query `$db->exec("...` would turn into this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO progress (user,time,count) VALUES (:user, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $user);
$stmt->execute();
```

Here you are preparing your sql statement `$sql` and then binding your parameter `$user`. There are a lot of good tutorials online and it is highly recommended to learn this process well.

Comment: yeah sorry, I don't know why but I actually have that, it dosent seem to be the issue

Comment: Can you give an example on how to use prepared statements?

Comment: @user4316754 what is `count` at the last line?

Comment: its just a dummy column, a way to make difference between time at insert and time at update, and its a datetime type meaning it should take in the minutes, even seconds with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: @user4316754 yes, I edited my answer with an example

Comment: @user4316754 well that `dummy column` is also improper code and probably what is causing your error. I'll edit my answer 1 more time

Comment: aaah, I can see how it prevents the SQL injection now, Thankyou, did I answer your question in what count does?

Comment: @user4316754 modified my answer. I have to go now though. If my answer is the one that worked for you, please accept it with a green checkmark so that future users know.

Comment: Thankyou, I think I now have a better understanding on where I went wrong, thanks again.